# How to set up an unbalance panel for analysis?

Tags: econometrics, panel-data, unbalanced-classes

I'm merging two datasets into a unbalance panel with 11 periods. My `dataset 01` has my dependent variable (normalised citation impact), and `dataset 02` has my regressors (network variables of centrality). To deal with simultaneity I'm estimating the dependent variable one year ahead of the network variables, for instance, $Y_t$, explained by the network of the period $X_{t-1, t-3}$. For instance, the citation score of the year $2000$ is explained by the network from the publications of $[1999,1997]$. The issue comes when I have information of the dependent variable, but no network, or the other way around. The way that I'm estimating now, is only when I have information on both, dropping the rest.

Question:

Should I include the non-matching periods, for instance, when I have info on $Y$, adding the network variables with `zeros`, or when I have information on the `X`, the network, add `Y` with `zeros`?

Answer (score 0):

Value 0 is different to having no value (missing). Observation with added zeros would go into your computation, e.g. an OLS regression. Observations with missing values are dropped before the regression is run. Thus, it will give you different results. You don't know if 0 is the desired value as it is missing. Do not plug in values you do not know, i.e. leave them as missing.

Also, in general, 0 is sometimes not a possible value for some variables.